# Find Query - Filter by array size after $elemMatch

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter, database

Is it possible to return records based on the size of the array after $elemMatch has filtered it down?

For example, if I have many records in a collection like the following:

```
[
{
    contents: [
        {
            name: "yorkie",
        },
        {
            name: "dairy milk",
        },
        {
            name: "yorkie",
        },
    ]
},
// ...
]
```

And I wanted to find all records in which their `contents` field contained 2 array items with their `name` field equal to "yorkie", how would I do this? To clarify, the array could contain other items, but the criteria is met so long as 2 of those array items have the matching field:value.

I'm aware I can use `$elemMatch` (or `contents.name`) to return records where the array contains at least one item matching that name, and I'm aware I can also use `$size` to filter based on the exact number of array items in the record's field. Is there a way that they can be both combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but today you can just use find

```
db.test.find({
    "$expr": { 
        "$gt": [ 
            { 
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$contents",
                    "initialValue": 0,
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": {
                            "if": {
                                "$eq": ["$$this.name", 'yorkie']
                             },
                             "then": {
                                 "$add": ["$$value", 1]
                             },
                             "else": "$$value"
                         }
                     }
                }
            },
            1
        ]
    }
})
```

The reduce will do the trick here, and will return the number of objects that match the criteria

Answer (score 2):

Not in a `find` query, but it can be done with an aggregation:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "contents.name" : "yorkie" } },
    { "$unwind" : "$contents" },
    { "$match" : { "contents.name" : "yorkie" } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "sz" : { "$sum" : 1 } } },    // use $first to include other fields
    { "$match" : { "sz" : { "$gte" : 2 } } }
])
```

I interpreted

> the criteria is met so long as 2 of those array items have the matching field:value

as meaning the criteria is met if at least 2 array items have the matching value in `name`.

Comment: I'm fairly new to MongoDB, so this is going well over my head. I'll give the docs a good look as to what the above means, but I can confirm it works! Thank you very much for your help.